# LTL symbolic notation reference

Tags: logic

I've always used the symbolic notation in Linear Temporal Logic (the one with diamonds <> and squares []) rather than the one with letters (G, X). Ç

Now I'm writing my thesis and I need a reference to some well-known article where LTL is described in these terms, but I'm unable to find any. All the foundational literature in verification (e.g. Emerson, Clarke) seems to use letters.

Any idea about where I should be looking for this reference would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can see [Wiki's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic) as well as the following [paper](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/papers/pdf/isical97.pdf).

Comment: See also  Dov M. Gabbay et alii, [Many-dimensional modal logics: theory and applications](https://books.google.it/books?id=P8jZwiExZYEC&pg=PA41) (2003).

Comment: See also [LTL](https://www.csc.kth.se/~mfd/Courses/Temporal_logic/lecture1.pdf).